# Emitir a constante da função discriminante - linear discriminant analysis [R]

Tags: r, função-discriminante

Como emitir a constante da função discriminante (ou constantes, se análise discriminante múltipla)? Segue o `dput` para auxílio na resposta.

```
structure(list(REAÇÃO = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), format.spss = "F11.0"), IDADE = structure(c(22, 
38, 36, 58, 37, 31, 32, 54, 60, 34, 45, 27, 30, 20, 30, 30, 22, 
26, 19, 18, 22, 23, 24, 50, 20, 47, 34, 31, 43, 35, 23, 34, 51, 
63, 22, 29), format.spss = "F11.0"), ESCOLARIDADE = structure(c(6, 
12, 12, 8, 12, 12, 10, 12, 8, 12, 12, 12, 8, 4, 8, 8, 12, 8, 
9, 4, 12, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 12, 16, 12, 12, 
12), format.spss = "F11.0"), SEXO = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), format.spss = "F11.0")), .Names = c("REAÇÃO", 
"IDADE", "ESCOLARIDADE", "SEXO"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Onde: `REAÇÃO` é a variável dependente e as demais independentes.

Como é análise discriminante simples (dois grupos), só terá uma constate para a única função do modelo. De adianto, esta constante tem o valor de `-4.438`. De preferência, peço que a mesma seja obtida com uma função simples de ser executada.

Comment: Olá Giovani, postar apenas a saída da análise não ajuda muito entender o que você precisa, a pergunta fica abstrata, tente ser um pouco mais específico com uma amostra de seus dados e da análise que realizou. Utilize o comando `dput(dados)` para captar uma amostrar reproduzível de seus dados e edite a pergunta.

Comment: Olá, Fernandes. Este post ajuda a entender o meu problema (obter as constantes na análise discriminante). Porém, o respondente não forneceu a resposta em script. Veja: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166942/why-are-discriminant-analysis-results-in-r-lda-and-spss-different-constant-t

Comment: Então, como o rapaz mencionou, no pacote MASS, não existe essa constante, mas sugere uma forma de obtê-la através de uma equação matemática, basta entender o conceito e implementar no R.

Comment: @Fernandes, editei a pergunta. Se conseguir me auxiliar, agradeço.

Comment: Infelizmente não conseguirei te ajudar, pelo menos não agora, mas tente olhar a função `PROC DISCRIM` do SAS, o conceito é o mesmo para obter a constante, pode-se usar o [PDF](http://www.ufrrj.br/institutos/it/deng/varella/Downloads/multivariada%20aplicada%20as%20ciencias%20agrarias/Aulas/ANALISE%20DISCRIMINANTE.pdf) como auxilio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazendo uma pesquisa do SO, acabei encontrando esse [tópico](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166942/why-are-discriminant-analysis-results-in-r-lda-and-spss-different-constant-t) em que é calculada constante baseada na fórmula matemática. O código abaixo vai te retornar o valor de `4.437946`, que difere do valor que você mesmo disse pelo sinal.

```
library(MASS)
fit <- lda(REAÇÃO ~ ., data = dados)
fit # show results
plot(fit)
groupmean <- (fit$prior%*%fit$means)
constant <- (groupmean%*%fit$scaling)
```

Posso estar enganado, mas pela estrutura que você disponibilizou e nas respostas do tópico que citei, você encontrou essa constante através do `SPSS` e, o valor de referência da variável `REAÇÃO` que ele usa é o inverso do que o `R` usa. Caso queira que o valor bata,

```
dados$REAÇÃO <- as.factor(dados$REAÇÃO)
dados2 <- within(dados, REAÇÃO <- relevel(REAÇÃO, ref = 2))
fit2 <- lda(REAÇÃO ~ ., data = dados2)
fit2 # show results
plot(fit2)
groupmean2 <- (fit2$prior%*%fit2$means)
constant2 <- (groupmean2%*%fit2$scaling)
```

Comment: Eu nem reparei que foi você quem deu a resposta que me baseei no Cross Validated. Pela diferença de sinais (o valor da resposta de referência), achei que no `SPSS` seria tudo invertido, como a segunda parte do meu exemplo. Quanto à parte do sempre terá o sinal invertido, não posso te afirmar, não sou usuário do `SPSS`. Sugiro que utilize outros bancos de dados de teste e verifique, mas mesmo assim certeza não será possível.

Comment: Pela fórmula da função discriminante, o centróide para o grupo 0 é: `z=(-4.438)+(-1.9832)+(4.6226)+(0.6609)=-1.1377`. Isso com base no livro que tenho. Se eu inverter a categoria de referência (com base na segunda parte do seu exemplo), o valor do centróide será totalmente diferente (dará `-7.7383`).

Answer (score 2):

Após realizada a análise discriminante com o package `MASS`, pode-se obter a constante. A expressão é:

```
groupmean<-(model$prior%*%model$means)
constant<-(groupmean%*%model$scaling)
constant
```

Onde `model` é o modelo discriminante. Por exemplo:

```
model<-lda(y~x1+x2+xn,data=mydata)
model
```

Atentando-se apenas para o **sinal** da constante.

**Qualquer outra resposta (útil) que complemente esta, ganhará a recompensa.**